# Unable to convert pandas string to numeric

Tags: python, regex

I have the following input dataframe. All types are strings. I would like to transform them to float. There are a wide variety of characters but ideally I'd like to keep only decimal separator and numbers. What is the best way to remove everything else?
I tried:

```
corp = corp.replace(r'\$', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Is there  a way to replace `all expect numeric AND comma` please?

```
                          JPY             JPY           JPY       JPY             JPY             JPY       JPY           JPY          JPY     JPY  ... JPY JPY JPY JPY JPY JPY JPY JPY JPY JPY
Update time                                                                                                                                              ...                                        
2018/8/13 10:15     $34,424,234.98  this is a str   ¥375,567,698  ¥304,734  ¥3,848,230,263    ¥101,677,219         0   ¥14,377,274  ¥47,719,464  ¥1,833  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2018/8/14 10:30     $34,424,234.98  ¥4,079,039,244  ¥375,567,698  ¥304,734  ¥3,131,351,753    ¥101,677,219         0   ¥14,377,274  ¥47,719,464  ¥1,833  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2018/8/15 10:30     $34,424,234.98  ¥4,644,436,742  ¥375,567,698  ¥304,734  ¥3,018,288,133    ¥101,677,219         0   ¥14,376,734  ¥48,551,464  ¥1,833  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

EDIT:

This is a solution...

```
corp = corp.replace(r'[a-zA-Z]|¥|,', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
corp = corp.replace(r'[^\d.]+', '', regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

This way, you will remove all chars other than digits and dots. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yNrQj6/1/).

**Details**

- `[^` - a negated character class start

  - `\d` - digit
  - `.` - dot
- `]+` - negated character class end, one or more occurrences